# Android SDK no encontrado

Tags: android, cordova, gradle

> Android SDK no encontrado . Confirma que esta instalado . Si no esta
>   en la localizacion por defecto , establece la variable de entorno
>   ANDROID_HOME.

Este es el problema que me devuelve `cordova` cuando uso el comando `cordova requirements` para saber si están todos los kit de desarrollo instalados , he probado a crear la variable android_home pero no ha servido.

Tengo el Android Studio instalado así que debería de encontrarlo pero al parecer por lo que he estado leyendo hay algún problema con la ultima actualización de `cordova`.

Tengo la duda de si se podría instalar todos los paquetes en una carpeta del proyecto y redirigir la búsqueda a esa carpeta para no tener que estar tocando el sistema, ¿se podría hacer ? [image: El error]

¿Alguien podría indicarme cómo se puede instalar el gradle?

Comment: Es una tontería pero, después crear la variable android_home, ¿has probado en una venta cmd nueva? Si era la vieja no notará el cambio.

Comment: Si pero no funciona

Comment: Buscando he visto esta solución http://stackoverflow.com/a/43014229/2927422